# REST API path parameters different types

Tags: c#, api, rest

I have a simple question, but I can not seem to find the answer somewhere on the internet.

When using path parameters in a REST API, are the following methods on different endpoints or will it conflict?

```
[HttpGet("{stringId}")]
public IActionResult GetObjectByStringId(string stringId) {
}

[HttpGet("{integerId}")]
public IActionResult GetObjectByIntegerId(int integerId) {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you hit one of your above mentioned endpoint, it will give error i.e. "The request matched multiple endpoints." You can solve this by specifying the type like below

```
[HttpGet("{integerId:int}")]
public IActionResult GetObjectByIntegerId(int integerId) {
}
```